# PushNotification OneSignal Issue

Tags: ios, notifications, onesignal

im using OneSignal SDK for PushNotification in my iOS App
when i done everything in the Project and run on real device, OneSignal Says :
*"This user has no push token and cannot be targeted."*
i checked every thing, ex : codes, profiles.

[image]

Comment: Could you perhaps post some code? You may have forgotten to register for push notifications in your appDelegate.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same problem.

Are you using objective-c? If so, you need to add the **-ObjC** flag to your project. Without it, the OneSignal SDK won't work.

On XCode, go to your target project > Build Settings > find **Other Linker Flags** and add **-ObjC** Flag.

[image]

Sometimes this could generate some conflicts with other SDKs (Such as Parse, GoogleMaps, Facebook..)

Take a look to my answer here for any possibly scenario about this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39135807/2551707