# OneSignal iOS issue "No Push Token" with SDK 2.0.7

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

I am confronting a weird error from OneSignal and push notifications. I have 3 devices (2 iPhones, 1 mini iPad). After i completed the entire process of Push notifications, only my iPad receives push notifications from OneSignal. All my devices are registered in my Developer Account and what i found is the most weird situation is that i NSLOG the `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` to see if each device connected receives a token and they all indeed get a token but for some reason OneSignal doesn't. Only the iPad token. The only difference that i could see is that the iPad is 9.3.2 and both iPhones are 9.3.4. The same app is installed on all devices, the oneSignal registration method is called from `AppDelegate`. Does anyone have been struggling with this issue as well? I attached an image of my oneSignal account. Thanks in advance.
[OneSignal All Users dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IHLS.png)

Comment: Can you try upgrading to the latest 2.0.9 SDK to see if this issue persists?

Comment: Still the same @JosephK .Its weird because my iPad is working great. The only difference between the iPad and the iPhones is the iOS version. Rather than that, there is no other difference at all.

Comment: can u give me replay of  may question??

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41095726/unable-to-integrate-one-signal-push-notification-in-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well finally after a week deleting and creating certificates more than 100 times, provisioning profiles, etc i found the problem.
I am using **objective-c** so it is necessary to use the **-ObjC** flag.
Go to project > Your Target > Build Settings > on the search bar write **other linker flags**, the section will come up and by double click on it, it will allow you to add **-ObjC**

[image]

Without this flag, the SDK wouldn't register the DeviceToken.
Also if you are using **Parse** SDK, or **GoogleMaps** SDK, or **Facebook** SDK, you probably will have a conflict. The posible solutions are:

- **Parse** SDK (I don't know if using parse server the conflict appears) : Delete `ParseCrashReporting ParseFacebookUtils ParseTwitterUtils`
- **Facebook** SDK (Maybe with new versions, this won't be necessary): delete `theFBAudienceNetwork`
- **GoogleMaps**:  Basically the GoogleMaps SDK doesn't work with the **-ObjC** flag, so i using now the WEB API using HTTP Calls with JSON Responses. (It is all explained on the GoogleMaps Developers website)

Hope this will help someone that is struggling badly like i was.
Please any question about this subject don't hesitate to ask me about it. I think that right now i know every possible fail.

Comment: This solution is no longer needed as the fix was issued from within the SDK and now the swizzling works with or without the -ObjC flag.

Comment: Great news @Joseph K

Answer (score 0):

You're my hero. I've been struggling with this for a month. I have even talked with OneSignal about it several times and they had no clue why this was happening to me! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed as of the [2.1.11](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK/releases/2.1.11) version of the SDK. Make sure to run a **pod update** if you're managing the SDK with CocoaPods.