# unable to integrate One-Signal Push notification in ios

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

i have tried to integrate One-signal as per given documents on their site but when i install framwork through podfile , at this time i got 0 percent dependancy

so how to integrate proper way??? in ios Xcode 8.

i have tried this Steps:

```
Option A: Use CocoaPods (Recommended)

Setting up CocoaPods on your system if you don't have it already.

    Make sure you have the latest 1.1.0 version by running pod --version from the terminal.
    Run the following to upgrade sudo gem install cocoapods

1.1 Make sure your current Xcode project is closed.
1.2 Run pod init
1.3 Run echo "pod 'OneSignal'" >> Podfile
     NOTE (React Native only) : Run echo "pod 'OneSignal', '~> 1.13.3'" >> Podfile instead.
1.3 Run pod install
1.4 Open the newly created .xcworkspace file.
```

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup

Comment: Yep, same here. Any solution?

Comment: yes i got solution and the problem was creating pod file

Comment: Hey, what you mean by creating pod file, I've already got podfile and i am trying to integrate within that only but not able to do so giving me duplicate entry error for swift project. Should i create another pod file or what i am not able to understand if you can help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed that the cocoaPods fails with iOS. I recommend doing the manual way.

1. Download the sdk from here:

https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK

2. Import the oneSignal.h and .m into your project.
3. Remember to go to capabilities and activate **Remote notifications**
4. Add this lines of code in your AppDelegate or wherever you would like to activate push notifications (Replace with your credentials):

   ```
   self.oneSignal = [[OneSignal alloc] initWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions
                                       appId:@"YOUR APP ID IN HERE"
                                       handleNotification:nil];
   ```
5. Finally follow my question and you are ready to go. Good Luck!
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/39135807/2551707